# Android selectable Bluetooth List

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

How can I make a popup on Android so when you click one of the devices it saves the device name to a variable. When I do it nothing happens and I really need some help with how to figure this out.

```
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // No bluetooth support on device
        }

        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null)
        {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
            String[] btarray;
            List<String> btlist = new ArrayList<String>();

            BTArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

            // get paired devices
            pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

            // put it's one to the adapter
            for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                btlist.add(device.getAddress());
            }


            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("BT")
                    .setItems(btlist2, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                            // of the selected item
                        }
                    });
            builder.create();


    }
```

```
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("BT")
                    .setItems(btlist2, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                            // of the selected item
                        }
                    });
            builder.create();
```

This didn't work

Comment: `This didn't work` means what exactly

Answer (score 0):

Okay the info you provided is incomplete so here is my guesswork.

1. You have adapter `BTArrayAdapter` instance but you are not using it.
2. You seems to have `btlist` but trying to use `btlist2`
3. You are building AlertDialog but not showing it.
4. Not sure if you are correctly requesting bluetooth permissions as you did not provide the info

So these are the things you need to check:

1. Once you created your adapter, you need to populate it with data somehow, e.g. `BTArrayAdapter.addAll(btlist);`
2. Make sure you're using the data list you are actually populating (`btlist`)
3. Once you built your dialog, make sure to show it (`builder.create().show();`)
4. Make sure you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />` in your manifest and make sure you are requesting location permissions dynamically (better try to populate list manually and see if it's showing, then you'll know it's something wrong with the permissions request)
5. I think instead of `setItems` of `AlertDialog.Builder` you should be using:

   ```
               .setAdapter(BTArrayAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                   }
               });
   ```

PS.: actually you are not discovering so you probably don't need to ask for location permissions.